# LINQ-ify Comparision Check

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists that I'm trying to compare values on, but the problem is that one is of type `List<string>` and the other is of type `List<SelectListItem>`.

This is what I have currently, which works fine, but I feel like it's a lot of overhead for such a simple comparison check.

```
List<SelectListItem> fullSubjects = SubRepo.GetSubjects();

//Create our custom list based off the diff
Manage.UserCustomSubjects = Manage.UserSubjects.Where(item => !StaticReferenceList.Contains(item)).ToList();
foreach (var s in Manage.UserCustomSubjects)
{
         var checkval = fullSubjects.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Text == s);
         if (checkval == null)
         {
             var additem = new SelectListItem();
             additem.Text = s;
             additem.Value = s;
             fullSubjects.Add(additem);
         }
}
```

The overall goal here is to create the `fullSubjects` list without any duplicate values.

Any suggestions on how I can clean this up, or possibly LINQify the comparison?

Comment: Did you mean for it to be `fullSubjects.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Text == s.Text);`? Have you looked at the `Distinct()` extension method?

Comment: Your description doesn't match Your code. How do You want to have "no duplicates" if You are only adding items to `fullSubjects`?

Comment: @JeffBridgman - I do believe that particular line is correct, as 's' is a string value and so is 't.Text'. I did look at Distinct(), but the problem was that the underlying compare of 'GetHasCode' was different for 'SelectItemList.Text' and 's'.

Comment: @GrzegorzW - I apologize for not clarifying the reasoning here, basically I have a static list of subjects and a custom field. The user could potentially add a custom subject that is already in the static list, thus the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach.  I left it broken out so it's easier to understand.

```
List<SelectListItem> fullSubjects = SubRepo.GetSubjects();

//Create our custom list based off the diff
Manage.UserCustomSubjects = Manage.UserSubjects.Where(item => !StaticReferenceList.Contains(item)).ToList();

var diff= Manage.UserCustomSubjects.Except(fullSubjects.Select(fs=>fs.Text));
var combined=fullSubjects.Union(diff.Select(d=>new SelectListItem {Text=d,Value=d}));
```

Shortened:

```
var fullSubjects = SubRepo.GetSubjects().Union(Manage.UserSubjects.Where(item => !StaticReferenceList.Contains(item)).ToList().Except(fullSubjects.Select(fs=>fs.Text)).Select(d=>new SelectListItem {Text=d,Value=d}));
```

Comment: This works great. The use of `.Except()` and `.Union()` was exactly what I needed here. Thanks!